# Restructure JSON output with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I get an array by json

```
[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"34"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age":"28"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "age":"36"}
]
```

but am expecting the result as below

```
[
    {"firstName":"John", "age":"34"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "age":"28"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "age":"26"}
]
```

Please help me with a solution using jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
var people = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"34"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age":"28"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "age":"36"}
];

$.each(people, function() {
   delete this.lastName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is transform each item in the array to a new type.  With jQuery, you can do this with the .map() function.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

```
var originalArray = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"34"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age":"28"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "age":"36"}
];

var newArray = $.map(originalArray, function(item) {
    return {
        "firstName": item.firstName,
        "age": item.age
    }
});
```